# Fatal error: Call to undefined function q() in ajaxCRUD.class.php on line 1861

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

When I tested ajaxcrud on my localhost ( http://www.ajaxcrud.com/ ). I got the following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function q() in ajaxCRUD.class.php on line 1861
```

Following is where the error exist.

```
function getFields($table){
    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table";
    $rs = q($query); // Line 1861

    $fields = array();
    foreach ($rs as $r){
        //r sub0 is the name of the field (hey ... it works)
        $fields[] = $r[0];
        $this->field_datatype[$r[0]] = $r[1];
    }

    if (count($fields) > 0){
        return $fields;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Hope someone can help me. Thank you very Much ....

Comment: My brain throws the same error. Where is `function q($query)...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `q()` is defined inside the `preheader.php` file inside the ajaxCRUD folder. Just include it before `ajaxCRUD.class.php`.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey, it's working. :)
I found that ajaxCRUD is not very suit for me. I got loads of errors and not easy for me to customize the code. Would u mind to recommend any other like ajaxCRUD, which should have user friendly and easier to customize the code? I saw that jqgrid is quite good in interface (http://www.trirand.net/demophp.aspx). How you think of it? Thank you :)

Comment: @ngenge, I'm sorry but I've never tried any of them and I do not have enough experience to suggest you one. I downloaded ajaxCRUD yesterday only to read the code and answer your question.

Comment: It's okay Jeffrey. Thank you for giving your time to help me. Thanks indeed :)